# Nodejs address already in use :::5000

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run a nodes app. I run `node app.js`. When I do, I get this error:

```
node:events:346
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1311:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1359:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1446:7)


Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1338:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -48,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 5000
}
```

I spent hours looking at possible solutions online but none have worked so far. Same codebase works great on a different machine. This error happens on Mac M1 chip.

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this?

I tried finding processes running on 5000, I tried to kill them etc... nothing worked so far. I am running node `15.14.0`.

I am on a `M1 Chip`, running `macOS Monterey`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Hey, why you just can't change port of your server?

Comment: Are you using macOS Monterey? since macOS 12, 5000 port is reserved for AirPlay Receiver https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332

Comment: You just need to find the app on that port and kill it. If that app is required, just use another port

Comment: Just run on another port instead killing the other application that is running on port `5000`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lee Jeonghyun was correct. The reason why `kill -9 PID` would never work is because of this:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682332

Control Center on Monterey is listening on 5000 as well.

I changed the port number in my nodejs app and the app started working again.

Comment: Amazing! This was it, thank you!

Comment: This was really helpful. Lee Jeonghyun Thank you 

Answer (score 51):

You should disable AirPlay on your mac. Because **macOS Monterey** started to listen to port 5000 and 8000.

*System Preferences > Sharing > untick AirPlay Receiver*

---

For **macOS Ventura**:

*System Settings > General > disable Airplay Receiver*

Comment: awesome. this should be the correct answer

Comment: Yes this saved me a lot of pain!

Comment: great this saves my time !

Comment: Man, I had this issue a long time and you just saved me from a lot of pain. Thanks!

Comment: This! This was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

List all process on mac:

```
sudo lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
```

You will see a list of process and its ports. Choose the process PID on 5000 port or any other port in the error: **EADDRINUSE: address already in use...**

Finally kill it if it is not an important app for you

```
kill -9 1234
```

Answer (score 3):

This also happened to me after upgrading to macOS Monterey from Big Sur.

Every port that I passed to my Node app appeared to be already in use.

You need to disable AirPlay on your mac.

System Preferences > Sharing > untick AirPlay Receiver

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqtmj.png)

Comment: I think you should tell him to kill any running process using this port.

Answer (score 1):

Did some investigation and found that macOS Monterey is using 5000 port for Airplay-Receiver. If you really want to use the port, then disable that feature in "System Preferences->Sharing".

Below medium post helped me:
[Port 5000 already in use — MacOS Monterey issue](https://medium.com/pythonistas/port-5000-already-in-use-macos-monterey-issue-d86b02edd36c)

[image]